# How to fetch contentNote records as per the contact record?

Tags: apex, soql, integration, content, contentnote

I am trying to fetch the note title, note body as per the related contact ID in one SOQL query as two SOQL queries won't serve the purpose.

In contentNote, We have the note title and note body but don't have the contact information. For contact information, there is contentDocumentLink but contentNote don't share any direct relation with contentDocumentLink.

When I run the below SOQL query in the Developer Console

```
SELECT Id, Title, TextPreview FROM ContentVersion 
WHERE ContentDocumentID IN (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '0030H000059CBKAQA4')
```

It throws below error:

> ERROR at Row:2:Column:59 Entity 'ContentDocumentLink' is not supported
>   for semi join inner selects

below query also don't serve the purpose as contentDocument object has note title but don't have the note body.

```
SELECT ContentDocument.title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId
= '0030H000059CBKAQA4'
```

It is really frustrating to get all the details in one query, could someone please suggest if note title, body and contact id can be fetched in a single 
query

Our purpose is to get all the data and integrate with another system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a relation between `ContentNote` and `ContentDocumentLink`. In order to get the `ContentNote` or `ContentVersion`, there are different ways of achieving it.

**Using 2 SOQL's**

- You will have to first query on `ContentDocumentLink` using the `LinkedEntityId` i.e. in your case it will be `ContactIDs` and collect all the `ContentDocumentId's`.
- Then after getting the `ContentDocumentID's`, you can query on `ContentNote` using the `ContentDocumentId's` retrieved from previous query.

This is how your sample code should look like

```
Set<Id> contactIds= new Set<Id>(); 
contactIds.add('0030H000059CBKAQA4'); //include all the contact ids for which you need to retrieve content note
Set<Id> contentDocumentIds = new Set<Id>();
//get all contentdocumentids so that you can query on contentnote
for(ContentDocumentLink conDoc : [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :contactIds]){
    contentDocumentIds.add(conDoc.ContentDocumentId);
}
//get all the content notes using contentDocumentIds
List<ContentNote> contentNotes = [SELECT Id, Title, Content from ContentNote where Id In: contentDocumentIds];
```

**Using relationship queries**

- You can get the `ContentNote` details using relationship fields by querying on `ContentDocumentLink` object and filtering it with `LinkedEntityId`

Your sample code for that would be

```
Set<Id> contactIds= new Set<Id>(); 
contactIds.add('0030H000059CBKAQA4'); //include all the contact ids for which you need to retrieve content note
List<ContentDocumentLink> conLinks = [select Id, LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN :contactIds];
system.debug(conLinks); //this will give only fields from ContentDocumentLink
system.debug(conLinks[0].LinkedEntityId); //this will give LinkedEntityId, in your case it will be Contact's ID
system.debug(conLinks[0].ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title); //to access ContentNote's title
system.debug(conLinks[0].ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData); //to access ContentNote's VersionData
```

In the above query, you can get the `ContentNote's` fields i.e. `Title` and `VersionData` along with its `LinkedEntityId` which would be your `ContactId`

You can refer the API document of [Content Note](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding but in the last query(contentNotes), we will get the notes but how we will make sure which note is related to which contact without using inner loops?

Comment: @gs650x Updated the answer with another approach, that should help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you again, I am exactly looking for this solution but this query is not returning expected results

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what are you expecting and what are you getting by the above query, so that I can see if I can help you on that.

Comment: I was expecting LinkedEntityID(contactID), noteTitle and note Discreption,
I ran the above query and passed a contactId has a note title and note body and when I ran the query in apex query return 2 fields id, linkedEntityID and didnot return rest field and when I ran the same in query editor it retun 3 fields one is id, then linkedEntityID and instead of note title and body I have got 3rd field named ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion no title not version data

Comment: That is the default behavior, in order to get the `ContentNote's` field, you will have to access it explicitly using dot notation as mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

According to ContentNote Data model, ContentDocumentLink holds the reference of ContentNote through ContentDocumentId and Related Records of Contact through LinkedEntityId.

If you describe those ContentNote and ContentDocumentLink objects you wont see any relationship between them.

Here, you need to create two separate queries.

Also, why extra query is creating the issue here still unclear from your question. There could be many approaches to solve a problem.

[image: ContentNote]

Comment: Thank you so much for responding but in two queries how I will match the contact IDs with the note title and note body without using inner loops?